# How to copy screenshot to png from a html_widget

Tags: r, shiny, htmlwidgets, shinyscreenshot, vtree

Follow-up question to this [R Shiny: Vtree plot not rendering with Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213705/r-shiny-vtree-plot-not-rendering-with-shiny)

With this code I generate a `vtree` htmlwidget. I would like to take a screenshot and save it in png.
For this I use `shinyscreenshot`. But I only get a screenshot of all the rest but not the html_widget:

```
library(shiny)
library(vtree)
library(shinyscreenshot)


# Define UI ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  
  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Cyl vtree"),
  
  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel(
    screenshotButton(selector = "body")
  ),
  
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    vtreeOutput("VTREE",  height = "800px")
  )
)

# Define server logic to plot ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output[["VTREE"]] <- renderVtree({
    vtree(mtcars, "cyl")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I used firefox and edge browser.

[image]

Comment: Works for me when I open in the app in the browser.

Comment: Hmmh. and the created png shows the vtree object?

Comment: I can reproduce, the vtree doesn't appear in the screenshots when I take the screenshot from the rstudio window or from firefox

Comment: Yep. Even if not pretty given the height = "800px": https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDj67.png. And if it matters: I use Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is maybe due to [`shinyscreenshot` limitations](https://github.com/daattali/shinyscreenshot#browser-support-and-limitations). Using another package ([`capture`](https://github.com/dreamRs/capture)) works:

```r
library(shiny)
library(vtree)


# Define UI ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  
  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Cyl vtree"),
  
  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel(
    capture::capture(
      selector = "body",
      filename = "all-page.png",
      icon("camera"), "Take screenshot of all page"
    )
  ),
  
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    vtreeOutput("VTREE",  height = "800px")
  )
)

# Define server logic to plot ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output[["VTREE"]] <- renderVtree({
    vtree(mtcars, "cyl")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is the output:

[image]